# Curl request with cert and key working via CLI but not via PHP

Tags: php, ssl, curl, certificate

I tried replicating a working curl command from CLI to a corresponding command via PHP and expected the same result. Instead I got a 400 bad request when doing the request via PHP.

I'm making a request for a Oath2 token via an API that requires you to use a certificate on all requests. The request works when I perform it with curl via CLI but when I try via PHP I get a 400 bad request response from the API.

This request with curl via CLI works.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url    https://sysorgoauth2.test.XXX.TLD/oauth2/v1/sysorg/token \
  --cert   /app/keys/eid.crt.pem \
  --key    /app/keys/eid.key.pem \
  --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  --verbose \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<ID>&client_secret=<SECRET>&scope=<SCOPE>"
```

This request with curl via PHP does not work.

```php
$headers = [
  'User-Agent: curl/7.74.0 via PHP',
  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Accept: */*',
];

$url = 'https://sysorgoauth2.test.XXX.TLD/oauth2/v1/sysorg/token';
$data = [
  'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
  'client_id' => '<ID>',
  'client_secret' => '<SECRET>',
  'scope' => '<SCOPE>',
];
$body = http_build_query($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/app/keys/eid.crt.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, '/app/keys/eid.key.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// For debug.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
$stream = fopen('/tmp/curl_debug.txt', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $stream);


$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This is the output from curl via PHP:

```
*   Trying (IP redacted):443...
* Connected to sysoauth2.test.XXX.TLD (IP redacted) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=X; ST=X; L=X; O=X; CN=sysoauth2.test.XXX.TLD
*  start date: May 20 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 20 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "sysoauth2.test.XXX.TLD" matched cert's "sysoauth2.test.XXX.TLD"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /oauth2/v1/sys/token HTTP/1.1
Host: sysoauth2.test.XXX.TLD
User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 187

* upload completely sent off: 187 out of 187 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Length: 172
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Connection: Close
<
* Closing connection 0
```

This is the output from curl via CLI:

```
*   Trying (IP redacted):443...
* Connected to sysorgoauth2.test.XXX.TLD (IP redacted) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=X; ST=X; L=X; O=X; CN=sysorgoauth2.test.XXX.TLD
*  start date: May 20 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 20 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "sysorgoauth2.test.XXX.TLD" matched cert's "sysorgoauth2.test.XXX.TLD"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /oauth2/v1/sysorg/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: sysorgoauth2.test.XXX.TLD
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 187
>
* upload completely sent off: 187 out of 187 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 161
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Connection: Close
<
{
  "access_token":"<ACCESS_TOKEN>",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "scope":"<SCOPE>"
}
* Closing connection 0
```

The part that differs between the two are:

```
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
```

I have tried all kinds of curl options in PHP to get this working. Perhaps `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` and `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` does not correspond to `--cert` and `--key`?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

I captured the requests for both CLI and PHP with Wireshark and there is a difference in the end of the sequence, *TCP Retransmission*. Not sure what that means. Will investigate.

**Wireshark CLI capture**

[image: Wireshark CLI capture]

**Wireshark PHP capture**

[image: Wireshark PHP capture]

**Wireshark PHP capture 2**

[image: Wireshark PHP capture 2]

**UPDATE 2**

Running the PHP code outside of my Docker environment does not produce the error. So this is somehow related to my dev environment.

Comment: `400 Bad Request` is not an SSL error, it is a "your HTTP request is malformed in some way or your POST data is bad". If there's not more error details contained in the body of the response you'll need to check on the server side for more details.

Comment: Yes, you are right I do get a response with the 400: `@ "error":"unauthorized_client", "error_description":"Client app (id = XXX) access is not allowed through this endpoint"`

Comment: We can't see the values you're inserting in there, but is the content of your `$body` really properly URL-encoded? I'd use an associative array and `http_build_query` to make sure that's not the issue here.

Comment: I switch to using `http_build_query` and tried, same error.

Comment: It turns out this was not a curl problem but a problem with the development environment. Running the code outside my Docker environment produced the desired results. Switching from Lando to Docksal also solved the problem so I guess this is a problem with the images used by Lando for my stack.